# VC++ native mutex heap corruption

Tags: visual-c++, mutex, heap-corruption

I have a native c++ library that gets used by a managed C++ application. The native library is compiled with no CLR support and the managed C++ application with it (/CLR compiler option).

When I use a std::mutex in the native library I get a heap corruption when the owning native class is deleted. The use of mutex.h is blocked by managed C++ so I'm guessing that could be part of the reason.

The minimal native class that demonstrates the issue is:

Header:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef __cplusplus_cli
#include <mutex>
#endif

namespace MyNamespace {

    class SomeNativeLibrary
    {
    public:
        SomeNativeLibrary();
        ~SomeNativeLibrary();
        void DoSomething();

#ifndef __cplusplus_cli
        std::mutex aMutex;
#endif

    };
}
```

Implementation:

```
#include "SomeNativeLibrary.h"

namespace MyNamespace {
    SomeNativeLibrary::SomeNativeLibrary()
    {}

    SomeNativeLibrary::~SomeNativeLibrary()
    {}

    void SomeNativeLibrary::DoSomething(){
        printf("I did something.\n");
    }
}
```

Managed C++ Console Application:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Unit Test Console:");

    MyNamespace::SomeNativeLibrary *someNativelib = new MyNamespace::SomeNativeLibrary();
    someNativelib->DoSomething();
    delete someNativelib;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The heap corruption debug error occurs when the attempt is made to delete the someNativeLib pointer.

Is there anything I can do to use a std::mutex safely in the native library or is there an alternative I could use? In my live code the mutex is used for is to ensure that only a single thread accesses a std::vector.

Comment: Perhaps you could put the `std::mutex` in a pimpl class that doesn't need to go in the `SomeNativeLibrary` header - only a pointer (or `std::unique_ptr<>`) to the pimpl class needs to be directly in the `SomeNativeLibrary` class definition.  That way the `SomeNativeLibrary` can be the same for the native and managed users (which I imagine it has to be to ever work).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a [CRITICAL_SECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as the lock instead. It's actually more efficient than a mutex in my case anyway since the lock is only for threads in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure were you reading your own post but there is a clue in your code:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus_cli
    std::mutex aMutex;
#endif
```

Member 'aMutex' compiles only if compile condition '__cplusplus_cli' is undefined.

So the moment you included that header in Managed C++ it vanished from definition.

So your Native project and Managed project have mismatch in class definition for beginners == mostly ends in Access Violation if attempted to write to location beyond class memory (non existing member in CLI version if instantiated there).
Or just HEAP CORRUPTION in managed code to put it simply.

So what you have done is no go, ever!
But I was actually amazed that you managed to include native lib, and successfully compile both projects. I must ask how did you hack project properties to manage that. Or you just may have found yet another bug ;)

**About question:** for posterity

Yes CRITICAL_SECTION helps, Yes it's more faster from mutex since it is implemented in single process and some versions of it even in hardware (!). Also had plenty of changes since it's introduction and some nasty DEAD-LOCKS issues.
example: https://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel.narkive.com/xS8sFPCG/criticalsection-deadlock-with-owningthread-of-zero
end up just killing entire OS. So lock only very small piece of code that actually only accesses the data, and exit locks immediately.

As replacement, you could just use plain "C" kernel mutex or events if not planning cross-platform support (Linux/iOS/Android/Win/MCU/...).
There is a ton of other replacements coming from Windows kernel.

// mutex
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, _T("MutexName"));
```

NOTE: mutex name rules 'Global' vs 'Local'.

// or event
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventw

```
HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, _T("EventName"));
```

to either set, or clear/reset event state, just call SetEvent(hEvent), or ResetEvent(hEvent).

To wait for signal (set) again simply

```
int nret = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, -1);
```

INFINITE define (-1) wait for infinity, a value which can be replaced with actual milliseconds timeout, and then return value could be evaluated against S_OK. If not S_OK it's most likely TIMEOUT.

There is a sea of synchronization functions/techniques depending on which you actually need to do !?:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-functions

But use it with sanity check.
Since you might be just trying to fix wrong thing in the end, each solution depends on the actual problem. And the moment you think it's too complex know it's wrong solution, simplest solutions were always best, but always verify and validate.